# Need guidance with FilteredSelectMultiple widget

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am sorry if it question might turn to be little broad, but since I am just learning django (and I am just hobbyist developer) I need some guidance which, I hope, will help someone like me in the future since I could not find any clear and easily comprehensible guide on using this widget. With your answers and help I will try to make this question thread at least guide-ish.

Material I found somewhat helpful for this topic:

[Django multi-select widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698435/django-multi-select-widget)

[Django: Replacement for the default ManyToMany Widget of Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495640/django-replacement-for-the-default-manytomany-widget-of-forms)

[Django's FilteredSelectMultiple widget only works when logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858181/djangos-filteredselectmultiple-widget-only-works-when-logged-in)

[Django FilteredSelectMultiple not rendering on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644521/django-filteredselectmultiple-not-rendering-on-page)

[Use the Django admin app's FilteredSelectMultiple widget in form](https://www.dangtrinh.com/2014/01/django-use-django-admin-apps.html)

[Get the chosen values from FilteredSelectMultiple widget in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709973/get-the-chosen-values-from-filteredselectmultiple-widget-in-django)

[Django FilteredSelectMultiple Right Half Does Not Render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51278591/django-filteredselectmultiple-right-half-does-not-render)

There were few others links, but they did not made anything clearer or added new information so I won't mention them.

Here is what I managed to understand (please correct me if I am wrong or add anything that I missed):

To create `FilteredSelectMultiple` widget firs I need to amend `forms.py` (as in any other widget creation process). Amended `forms.py` should have `from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple` import and `Media` class. `forms.py` code should look like this (**please correct me, because probably it is wrong somewhere**):

```
from django import forms
from catalog.models import DrgCode  
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple
from django.conf import settings #without it I get an error that settings not defined

class CalculatorForm(forms.Form):
    drg_choice = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=DrgCode.objects.all(), widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Somethings", is_stacked=False), required=True)

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': (os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, '/static/admin/css/widgets.css'),),
        }
        js = ('/admin/jsi18n',)
```

**Questions about this part:**

1. Am I right about `django.conf` import? Since I did not see it
   imported in any material I found. **Answer: during my test I determined that `django.conf` import is necessary if using `settings.BASE_DIR` part. In various sources there was two ways of writing `css` path, this one worked for me.**
2. Do I need to create `widgets.css` and corresponding directory? Or
   django will find it itself? Since there is no such file or directory
   generated after I created skeleton-website using `django-admin
   startproject` cmd? **Answer: No. There is no need to create `widgets.css` or any of the files since django finds them itself.**
3. Same question as previous for `jsi18n` part. Also what is this? I
   assume its javascript file, but it has no extension for some reason.
   Also I cannot find it anywhere? Should I create it? How to do that?
   Or I can copy it from somewhere? **Partial answer: no need to create it. Just point at it in `urls.py`. Still do not know exactly that kind of file it is (or where it is)**

After amending `forms.py` I should ammend `urls.py`by adding `url(r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', name='jsi18n')`

So `urls.py` now look like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url 


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog',
    name='jsi18n'),
]
```

**Questions:**

4. Am I doing it wright or should I just add it below `urlpatterns`? **Answer: This method if fine.**

Now I need to set `HTML` template file for form to render (like in any other case). Code for it (file named `DrgCalculator.html`):

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'jsi18n' %}" > </script>

  {{ form.media }}

  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

5. This part seems more or less clear. But maybe I should amend
   something or know about? **Answer: Should be changed. Will write full code below.**

Lastly I need to adjust `views.py` to set where this form and everything related with it happens.

From what I understand code in this part is more or less is not directly related with widget, but to complete everything and make working example I will use code I leaned/got in [this (very good) django tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

from catalog.models import DrgCode
from catalog.forms import CalculatorForm

def DrgCalculator(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CalculatorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'DrgCalculator.html')
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'DrgCalculator.html', context)
```

**Questions:**

6. Any remarks on this part of the code? **Answer: Missing `else: form = DrgCalculator()`. Will write amended code below.**
7. How I will access values which user choose using
   `FilteredSelectMultiple`? I imagine I should clean data in
   `forms.py` like with other widgets. So I should add nested function
   below to my `class CalculatorForm` in `forms.py` am I right? **Answer: Yes, data should be cleaned like in other cases. Function is correct.**

   `def clean_CalculatorForm(self):
           drg_choice = self.cleaned_data['drg_choice']
           return drg_choice`
8. Data I will get after cleaning will be list or dictionary? Am I
   right? **Answer: No, from this widget user input received as QuerySet**

That is all my questions, sorry for long thread, I tried to make it as clear as possible. If I need to clarify something, please let me know. I will try to edit and update this, to make it friendly for people who will read it in future.

EDIT1: Answered some of my questions.

EDIT2: Answered rest of my questions.

Comment: Don't we all start somewhere? :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After spending few days of research and testing I managed to get `FilteredSelectMultiple` widget working outside admin page in user form. As promised in question, I will try to synthesize my accumulated knowledge into some sort of guide which, I hope, will help someone like me in the future. Please note that I am far from professional (just a hobbyist with no computer engineering background to be precise) so my observations might not be exactly correct or the way I done it might not the best one. Despite that it might help you to get on the right track.

So to begin with `FilteredSelectMultiple` widget first of all - `forms.py` have to be amended by importing widget, creating field for it (similar like with regular widgets) and adding nested `Media` class.  Code example:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple    

class DrgCalculator(forms.Form):
        drg_choise = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=DrgCode.objects.all(),
                                                          label="Something",
                                                          widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Title", is_stacked=False),
                                                          required=True)
        
        class Media:
            css = {
                'all': ('/static/admin/css/widgets.css',),
            }
            js = ('/admin/jsi18n',)
        
        def clean_drg_choise(self):
            drg_choise = self.cleaned_data['drg_choise']
            return drg_choise
```

As I determined during my test and research `class Media` should be copied as written and require no changes for widget to work. Files mentioned in this class will be found by django itself so no need to search and copy them (like told in some of the material I read).

After creating form `urls.py` should be amended. During testing I found out, that in newer django versions (or at lest one I used)  `javascript_catalog` is renamed and url provided cannot be string. So code should look like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.urls import re_path
from django import views as django_views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^jsi18n/$', django_views.i18n.JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='jsi18n'),
]
```

Now for the `html` template I am sure that there is more ways of doing it so I just provide example:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div id='frame'>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div id='sk_body'>
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Fill required fields</legend>      
                <form>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <table>
                        {{ form.media }}
                        {{ form.as_table }}
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'jsi18n' %}"></script>
                    </table>
                        <input type="submit" value="Count">
                </form>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

To receive data from this widget fairly standard code in `views.py` should be used, example code I used:

```
def DRG_calcualtor(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DrgCalculator(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            choosen_drg = form.cleaned_data['drg_choise'] #result as QuerySet
            choosen_drg_list = list([str(i) for i in choosen_drg]) #you can convert it to list or anything you need             
                  
            return render(request, 'DRGcalculator_valid.html')
           
        context = {
            'form': form,
            }
        return render(request, 'DRGcalculator.html', context)
    
    else:
        form = DrgCalculator()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        }
    return render(request, 'DRGcalculator.html', context)
```

Comment: The problem with `FilteredSelectMultiple` is that it only works when you are logged in as admin

Comment: When extending `admin/base_site.html` the best thing to do is put the media in head: `{% block extrahead %}{ super.block }}{{ form.media }}{% endblock %}`